# how can i group a large number of elements quickly

Tags: r, for-loop, grouping

I've created some 'data' here as an example. It's contains 100 elements where each start with a letter and are followed by 3 random numbers.

I want to know the best/quickest way to convert them into groups like i've started to do in the for loop.

Assume i need to create 50 groups and instead of 100 elements in 'data' there are a million.

The groupings themselves will be fairly random. I've used A000-A599 and A600-A999 as the first 2 groupings in my example but the groupings are not neatly spaced out e.g B000-B599 and B600-B999 are not necessarily the next groupings. The next groupings could for example be B000-C299,C300-C799,C800-D499 etc. I would need to enter these groupings manually.

I'm guessing a for loop isn't the best way to do this as it would take a long time to complete the loop.

```
library(stringr)
library(magicfor)

data <- paste(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
    sample(str_pad(000:999, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0"), 100, replace = T), sep = "")

magic_for()

for(x in seq_along(data)){

 if( grepl("A[0-5]", data[1])){
range <- "A000-A599"
}elseif( grepl("A[6-9]", data[1])){
range <- "A600-A999"
}

put(range)
}
```

Comment: How are you defining "similarity" of the elements? What makes two elements be in the same group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The groupings themselves will be fairly random. I've used A000-A599 and A600-A999 as the first 2 groupings in my example but the groupings are not neatly spaced out e.g B000-B599 and B600-B999 are not necessarily the next groupings. The next groupings could for example be B000-C299,C300-C799,C800-D499 etc.

Since your groups are lexicographic intervals, you could use rolling joins. In this case you only need to specify the lower bound for each group:

```
library(data.table)

# define decrement function
dec = function(x){
  ltr = substr(x, 1, 1)
  num = as.integer(substr(x, 2, 4))

  w0 = num == 0L
  ltr = replace(ltr, w0, LETTERS[match(ltr[w0], LETTERS) - 1L])
  num = replace(num - 1L, w0, 999L)

  sprintf("%s%03d", ltr, num)
}

# enumerate lower bounds and derive ranges
rangeDT = data.table(lb = c("A000", "A600", "B000", "C300", "C800"))
rangeDT[, ub := dec(shift(lb, type="lead", fill="Z999"))]
rangeDT[, range := sprintf("%s-%s", lb, ub)] 

#      lb   ub     range
# 1: A000 A599 A000-A599
# 2: A600 A999 A600-A999
# 3: B000 C299 B000-C299
# 4: C300 C799 C300-C799
# 5: C800 Z998 C800-Z998
```

Then the rolling update join is...

```
DT = data.table(x = data)    
DT[, range := rangeDT[.SD, on=.(lb = x), roll=TRUE, x.range]]
```

The result looks like

```
> head(DT)
      x     range
1: C965 C800-Z999
2: Q973 C800-Z999
3: V916 C800-Z999
4: C701 C300-C799
5: A363 A000-A599
6: F144 C800-Z999
```

If your data were numeric, `cut` or `findInterval` from base R would work, but for whatever reason those do not support strings.

Comment: Not sure if i'm doing something wrong. I've tried changing the lower bounds and sometimes get an error of "Error in x[list] <- values : replacement has length zero ". Sometimes it works depending on what ranges i assign but i can't see why it works with some and not others. For example this throws the error: rangeDT = data.table(lb = c("A000", "A200", "A900", "C300", "C800"))
     rangeDT[, ub := shift(dec(lb), type="lead", fill="Z999")]

Comment: @Steve My bad on the logic of deriving `ub`. I think it's fixed now

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
> #Round function
> roundUp <- function(x,to=10) {
+   to*(x%/%to + as.logical(x%%to))
+ }
> #Create a dataframe for easy store
> df <- data.frame(data = data, stringsAsFactors = F)
> df %>%
+   mutate(C = substr(data, 1, 1),
+          N = as.integer(substr(data, 2, 4))) %>%
+   mutate(N = roundUp(N, to = 500)) %>%
+   mutate(data2 = paste0(C, N)) %>%
+   select(data, data2)
    data data2
1   U493  U500
2   A429  A500
3   N564 N1000
4   W656 W1000
5   J978 J1000
6   B232  B500
7   D240  D500
8   I796 I1000
9   E831 E1000
...(truncated)
```

The `data2` field contains the new groups

Answer (score 3):

Using the `tidyverse` packages, I would convert your `data` vector into a `data.frame` (or `tibble`) format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(my_variable = data) %>%
  mutate(
    first_char = substr(my_variable, 1, 1),
    random_numbers = substr(my_variable, 2, 4)
  )
```

Once you've gotten that far, it's easy to group the data however you want. Your loop could be achieved like so:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    group = ifelse(as.numeric(random_numbers) < 600, "000-599", "600-999"),
    desired_result = paste0(first_char, group)
  )
```

I recommend reading the following (free) ebook cover to cover, it will equip you with a bunch of useful tools for everyday R tasks like the one you've outlined:

https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(data.table)    
ranges <- c(paste0(LETTERS, "[0-5]"),paste0(LETTERS, "[6-9]"))



final <-lapply(ranges, function(y)  {
                                    matches <- grepl(y, data)
                                    if(sum(matches)>0){
                                    tmp <-data.table(element=data[matches], range=
                                                       paste0(str_sub(y,1,1), str_sub(y,3,3),0,0,"-", str_sub(y,1,1), str_sub(y,5,5),9,9))}
                                    else return(NULL)
                                      })
final_2 <- rbindlist(final)


#    element   range
#      A374 A000-A599
#      B498 B000-B599
#      B064 B000-B599
#      C131 C000-C599
#      C460 C000-C599
#      C099 C000-C599


structure(list(element = c("A374", "B498", "B064", "C131", "C460",  "C099", "C193", "E428", "E108", "E527", "E138", "E375", "E312",  "F046", "F417", "F094", "G142", "G461", "G068", "H372", "H523",  "H027", "H506", "I470", "I169", "I050", "I495", "I405", "J298",  "K165", "K169", "K131", "L510", "L210", "L277", "N257", "N554",  "N452", "N484", "N247", "N373", "N492", "O347", "O221", "O176",  "P578", "P477", "Q062", "Q257", "Q083", "R306", "S415", "S154",  "S226", "S400", "T132", "T181", "T321", "V109", "V118", "V267",  "W381", "W047", "X317", "X192", "Y390", "Y132", "Y327", "Y141",  "Y353", "Z429", "C981", "D813", "F934", "G910", "G673", "G664",  "I754", "I624", "L603", "N991", "N996", "O689", "O932", "P854",  "P689", "P761", "P681", "Q631", "S620", "T923", "T841", "U787",  "U929", "W942", "W702", "X770", "X880", "Y719", "Y969"), range = c("A000-A599",  "B000-B599", "B000-B599", "C000-C599", "C000-C599", "C000-C599",  "C000-C599", "E000-E599", "E000-E599", "E000-E599", "E000-E599",  "E000-E599", "E000-E599", "F000-F599", "F000-F599", "F000-F599",  "G000-G599", "G000-G599", "G000-G599", "H000-H599", "H000-H599",  "H000-H599", "H000-H599", "I000-I599", "I000-I599", "I000-I599",  "I000-I599", "I000-I599", "J000-J599", "K000-K599", "K000-K599",  "K000-K599", "L000-L599", "L000-L599", "L000-L599", "N000-N599",  "N000-N599", "N000-N599", "N000-N599", "N000-N599", "N000-N599",  "N000-N599", "O000-O599", "O000-O599", "O000-O599", "P000-P599",  "P000-P599", "Q000-Q599", "Q000-Q599", "Q000-Q599", "R000-R599",  "S000-S599", "S000-S599", "S000-S599", "S000-S599", "T000-T599",  "T000-T599", "T000-T599", "V000-V599", "V000-V599", "V000-V599",  "W000-W599", "W000-W599", "X000-X599", "X000-X599", "Y000-Y599",  "Y000-Y599", "Y000-Y599", "Y000-Y599", "Y000-Y599", "Z000-Z599",  "C600-C999", "D600-D999", "F600-F999", "G600-G999", "G600-G999",  "G600-G999", "I600-I999", "I600-I999", "L600-L999", "N600-N999",  "N600-N999", "O600-O999", "O600-O999", "P600-P999", "P600-P999",  "P600-P999", "P600-P999", "Q600-Q999", "S600-S999", "T600-T999",  "T600-T999", "U600-U999", "U600-U999", "W600-W999", "W600-W999",  "X600-X999", "X600-X999", "Y600-Y999", "Y600-Y999")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```